# GWT Designer won't launch after fresh installation

Tags: toolkit, gwt-designer, google-plugin-eclipse

I'm trying to install Google Web Toolkit designer but no success so far. After spending few days struggling I've tried many different approaches including fresh installation of different versions of eclipse.
I can create a new web applications and it runs just fine. My problem now is to lauch the GWT designer. This is the error I'm getting.

Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

and these are the details of the error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.multi.DesignerEditor
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.loadClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.loadClass(BundleHost.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.loadClass(AbstractBundle.java:1207)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorManager.createPart(EditorManager.java:875)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:609)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2945)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2850)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2842)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2793)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2789)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2773)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu.openEditor(OpenWithMenu.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractDecoratedTextEditor$18.openEditor(AbstractDecoratedTextEditor.java:1969)
    at org.eclipse.ui.actions.OpenWithMenu$2.handleEvent(OpenWithMenu.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)

I've seen many other people with the same issues and there are different solutions to solve this issue. I've tried every songle thing I've found on the forums (Create new workspace, tried with different jdk versions but no success.

My environment:

Eclipse Indigo 3.7
Java 1.6.0_37
Windows 7

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks,

J

Comment: "This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor". Can you paste in the code of the class that you are trying to open? It sounds like you don't have the proper constructor (with no arguments) setup? Also how are you launching the GWT Designer? Open With->GWT Designer or via another means?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might need some of the window builder plugins, check the indigo update site in (help -> install new software)... select the indigo update site in "work with" (it should be in there).  Then set the filter text to something like "Window" and you should see some window builder plugins under the "General Purpose Tools" group.  I think you might need "WindowBuilder Core" and "WindowBuilder Core UI", I also have "WindowBuilder GroupLayout Support" installed on mine so you can add that one in if you like.